# What does $d|z|$ mean in complex integral $\int_Cf(z)d|z|$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

The problem is:
Use the definition of complex integral $\int_Cf(z)d|z|$ over a curve to 
evaluate the integral $\int_C\frac{d|z|}{\overline{z}}$, where $C=\{e^{it}:t\in[0,2\pi]\}$.

The $d|z|$ part is confusing me. The question seems pretty easy. I am sure I can easily solve it if I knew the definition of $\int_Cf(z)d|z|$.  I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: This is an integral with respect to arc length.  I'm sure it's explained in your text.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a typo, and should be printed as $|dz|$. For your curve $C$ this would lead to $|dz|=dt$ $(0\leq t\leq 2\pi)$.

Note that $d|z|$ means the infinitesimal change in $|z|$, hence would be $\equiv0$ along $C$.

Comment: I will treat it like a |dz|. Thank you.